# Using Visual Studio Diagnostic Tool to investigate memory consumption/leak

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017

In a WPF application I'm working on, I got the following memory-usage profile from Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools (see image below).

So my program keeps allocating more and more memory until I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I am new to VS Diagnostic Tools, so the question is: how do I use this window, or the information it provides, to find out the culprit of this memory consumption?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the memory reaches a level that is suspiciously high, you'll want to pause the debugger and then use "Take Snapshot" to get a snapshot of the memory allocations. You can then analyze which objects are using different amounts of memory.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2017) for more details on measuring memory usage with the diagnostic tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, by performing your suggestions, the "Memory Diff" view made me realize a given costly constructor was inadvertently being called inside a tight loop. Now I am able to fix that, which was far from obvious and would be a pain to locate without Diagnostic Tools!

Answer (score 2):

It also depends a lot on what you are doing, i.e. do you have one gigantic file? or do you have thousands or maybe millions of smaller objects and files or images?

A situation I ran into recently with high memory usage was with handles from system.graphics, both my number of handles (task manager->performance, system handles) and memory were growing and way more than they should have been. I had forgotten to dispose of 10 bitmaps each iteration. I called dispose() on those bitmaps and it fixed my problem.

With VS's memory snapshot, you can take multiple snapshots and compare them to see what's changed. I used task manager just as much as I used VS's managed memory tools. You can use task manager's -> Processes to see whats going on. You can add columns to track objects such as handles, threads, and GDI objects by clicking view -> select columns.